# Android PHP query not working

Tags: php, android, mysql

My php code works and its says the result is succes and also in my android but its not doing my query to update a row its just saying succes but not updating.
And I very sure that the `CarStatus` and the `Car_No` are in my db.

## PHP QUERY

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['txtCarNo']) && isset($_POST['txtCarStatus']))
{
    $carNo = $_POST['txtCarNo'];
    $carStatus = $_POST['txtCarStatus'];

    $query = "UPDATE tbl_cars SET carStatus = '$carStatus' WHERE Car_No = '$carNo'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($result > 0){
        echo "success";
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "failed";
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

## MOBILE

```
HashMap post = new HashMap();

    post.put("txtCarNo",tvCarID.toString());
    post.put("txtCarStatus","for approval");

    PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(DetailActivity.this, post, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            if (s.contains("success")) {
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Wait for owners approval", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, RenterTabs.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/rent2.php");
}
```

> EDIT

## Connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***"; 
$dbname = "***";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: `$result > 0` is logically wrong. `mysql_query` returns a statement handle, or a boolean false. it NEVER returns an integer. it should be `if ($result === false) { echo 'failed'; } else { echo 'success'; }`. And note that an update which didn't update any rows is NOT a failure. it's simply an update that didn't change anything. you need to check affected_rows instead.

Comment: Why isnt the php script echoing something in case both isset()s fail?

Comment: @MarcB - how can I check the affected rows sir? Because I'm new to php and anrdoid sir. Don't have any idea...

Comment: @Jengjeng When i type your question on google `how can I check the affected rows sir?`  : , i get at a top hit **[the answer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)**

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Not a good idea pointing OP at a `mysql_` API call.

Comment: @RiggsFolly : true'ish , i was assuming that the big fat warning would catch OPs eye, but you are right , i may be wrong. my point was about googling.

Answer (score 0):

On `post.put("txtCarNo",tvCarID.toString());` tvCarID needs a `.getText` 
so instead make it `postData.put("txtCarNo",tvCarID.getText().toString());`